# What are the implications of having main plugin file name different to plugin slug?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, directory

I have inherited a plugin.  If the plugin is called `example` and is in `/wp-content/plugins/example` what are the implications if the main plugin file is called `example-plugin.php` and not just `example.php`?

I know that the plugin will work, but are there any unforeseen problems that could arise?

I do understand that changing it will cause the plugin to deactivate, but there is a very clear notice.

FWIW this has come about because I am trying to use the internal updater on a custom Pro version of a plugin (that isn't in the repository) using this: [getbutterfly.com/custom-wordpress-plugin-update-server](https://getbutterfly.com/custom-wordpress-plugin-update-server) and it only works if the plugin file name matches the plugin slug

Comment: I have never encountered such problems, so I don't know either. Also, [Hello Dolly](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/hello-dolly/tags/1.7.2/hello.php) used a name that's different from the plugin slug (which should match the `Plugin Name` header, e.g. `my-plugin` if the header's value is `My Plugin`). But we should follow the [plugin handbook's recommendation](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/#getting-started) - "*it’s also good to name this file after your plugin*".

Comment: "*it only works if the plugin file name matches the plugin slug*" - that is actually a plugin-specific requirement. What the plugin handbook stated, was simply a recommendation and not a requirement. So perhaps the plugin author was encouraging developers to follow the handbook's recommendation, but you'll need to consult them for the exact reasons why did they make that requirement.

Comment: @SallyCJ this requirement was actually for the code I want to use for having my custom plugin updated by the native wordpress process.  It isn't for the plugin itself.

Comment: I was saying that you could actually modify the [custom updater plugin](https://getbutterfly.com/custom-wordpress-plugin-update-server/) so that the plugin being checked doesn't need to have its main file's name be matching the plugin slug. ( basically, by changing all the `$plugin_slug . '/' . $plugin_slug . '.php'` to `$plugin_slug . '/example-plugin.php'` ) I already tried & tested that with WordPress v6.3.1, and my (test) plugin was updated just fine with the help of that custom updater plugin/code.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ - I was considering that, but I have been under the pump with a flaky server.  The original question was really an "out of curiosity" thing. :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's only a good pratice to adopt this naming convention. As long as you have in the header of your main file the meta (at last `Plugin name: Name of Your Plugin`, WordPress will **automatically recognize this file for being the main one**.

Be aware that at the top of this file [you should write at least](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/header-requirements/#minimum-fields) :

```
/*
 * Plugin Name: YOUR PLUGIN NAME
 */
```

In the **plugin handbook**, WordPress [it is written](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-basics/#getting-started) :

> Create a new PHP file (it’s also good to name this file after your
> plugin, e.g. plugin-name.php).
>
> […] Only one file in the plugin’s folder should have the header comment —
> if the plugin has multiple PHP files, only one of those files should
> have the header comment.

As you can see, it's only a naming convention. It is not mandatory.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Unfortunately it does affect the operation of the updater I am trying to get going, that requires that the main plugin file be named the same as the plugin slug.